# Python to export SQL results to Excel

Tags: python, excel

I want to export the result of a SQL query to an Excel sheet using Python.

#### Code

```
sql='''
      Select * from PTWorkOrderTasks 
     '''

// this is the code to generate sql result
sql_result= self.account.DBService().ExecuteQuery(sql,{})

if sql_result.Rows.Count>0:
  (--code to export to excel--)
```

I need Python code to export this query result to Excel.

Can anyone help me correct this?

Comment: The most simple way to export data in a format that is readable by Excel is to export it in CSV format. See this: http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer

Answer (score 0):

You can use xlrd. See the [tutorial](https://github.com/python-excel) on Github.